# I can't save my redirect URI in Facebook for Developers

Tags: laravel, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to add Facebook Login button in my localhost using Facebook for Developers. when I insert the URI in 'Redirect URI Validator' and click 'save changes' the 'saved' sign showed up and the page is reloaded but then the URI is gone and nothing submitted.

I have a good Internet connection and everything is going right but I cant submit my URI.

here is the input I'm struggling with:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy9Sh.png)

and here is my URI:

```
https://localhost:8000\callback\facebook
```

I hope I can find help.

Comment: forward slashes `/` instead of backslashes \

Comment: Did you try `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: I tried everything and nothing worked. I tried to use Firefox instead of Chrome and didn't work too.

Comment: Facebook might not allow you to callback to localhost. You may need to set up a vhost for your local environment